# Android Google Analytics dispatch interval

Tags: android, google-analytics

In the document, it mentions that we can have a dispatch interval such that page view will be automatically dispatched after x seconds.

I have the code like the following

```
tracker.startNewSession("UA-YOUR-ACCOUNT-HERE", 20, this);
```

I sure **trackPageView()** is called as I can see those pageview are stored into "google_analytics.db" which is the database that google analyitcs used to store non-dispatching pageview. However, it doesn't send to Google Analytics after 20 seconds

In log, it keeps reporting **scheduling next dispatch** when I call **trackPageView()**.